# The TextBoxt return empty value in Datalist

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

May be my Question repeated before but really I am tired how to solve this problem, as when this event fire the **textbox** return empty :

```
 protected void Btn_publicpost_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
 {

    string x = txt_publicpost.Text;
 }
```

I tested the update panel out of the **datalist** and it worked well , so the problem may be at **datalist**.

```
<asp:DataList ID="DL_userpost" runat="server" CssClass="single-posts" RepeatColumns="1"
    OnItemCommand="DL_userpost_ItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="single-posts">
            <div class="post-user">
                <a href="#"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="post-container-all">
                <div class="post-user-single-img">
                    <asp:Image ID="Img_Twasol" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Post_File")%>' Width="130"
                        Height="99" /></div>
                <div class="post-user-single-data-tabs">
                    <div class="post-user-single-data-title">
                        <%#Eval("User_Name")%>
                    </div>
                    <div class="post-user-single-data-text">
                        <%#Eval("Post_Content")%>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
             <div class="comment">
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UPPublicComment" runat="server" >
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <asp:Panel ID="pnpublicpost" runat="server" DefaultButton="Btn_publicpost">
                                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt_publicpost" CssClass="comment-tabs2"></asp:TextBox>
                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="Btn_publicpost" CommandName="publicpost" ValidationGroup="publicpost"
                                        runat="server" OnClick="Btn_publicpost_Click" Style="display: none" />
                                    <asp:Label ID="LblpublicpostPID" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Post_ID")%>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                                </asp:Panel>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
         </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

> SO where the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your can't use dynamic references like txt_publicpost from DataList and other repeaters. 
Try something like this

```
protected void Btn_publicpost_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
   var box = (TextBox)((ImageButton)sender).Parent.FindControl("txt_publicpost");
   string x = box.Text;
}
```